# SSIS: Transform data to fixed width text with variable rows

Tags: sql-server, file, text, ssis

I'm trying to make a plain text with SSIS from a SQL select. The problem is that SSIS makes the file like a table, and I need it in a specific format.

For example, I have this result:

```
bill_id    | concept    |concept_type |amount |
-----------|------------|-------------|-------|
334455     |concept1    |product      |12     |
334455     |concept2    |product      |10,5   |
334455     |concept3    |service      |45,8   |
334455     |concept4    |service      |1,05   |
334455     |concept5    |service      |12,5   |
334455     |concept6    |service      |14,6   |
334455     |concept7    |service      |108    |
```

And I need to transform to something like this:

```
00   334455                                          
19                                                   
10   concept1       12.00                            
20   concept2       10.50                            
17                                                   
10   concept3       45.80                            
20   concept4        1.05                            
30   concept5       12.50                            
40   concept6       14.60                            
50   concept7      108.00                            
21   total         204.45
```

So, I have the first line, the ID, which is the value of first column. The 00 tells that line is the ID. 
Next we have the 19, telling starts product concepts, then the line of each concept.
Same with 17, but with service concepts. 
The last, 21, is the total of all concepts.

I know it can be done with a C# app, but I was trying to do with SSIS so I can make a dts file.

Is it possible? How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Since you know how it is done in C#, you can add a script component and write your code in C# there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several approaches for your task:

1. As said in comments, you can write a Script Transform in C# and do whatever you want. It is a way to go, especially for complex transforms.
2. For a pure SSIS way, you have to break your task onto subtasks. I.e. extract data from SQL, get a list of all *bill_ids*, in a loop group by *bill_id* and calculate total, query SQL data filtered by *bill_id* and get list of *concept_type*, organize loop on *concept_type*, query SQL data filtered by *bill_id* and *concept_type*, do a dataflow with Row Number script. Then store results as an Recordset and collect all recordsets in a subsequent loop.
   You see the problem? You transformation requires a lot of data grouping, and can be done on a whole recordset. SSIS shines when you do streaming data transformations, i.e. line-scoped.

Back to your task - I would rather do it SSIS and C# Script Task. SSIS *Execute SQL Task* fetches your resultset and stores it in an Object variable, then *Script Task* gets dataset from Object variable and do all transformations with LINQ etc. Then store the results to the file with C#.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if I was overlooking an easy way to do it with SSIS. The data is actually more complex, same as transformation, I also thought of doing it with sql, making cursors, but I think the easiest way will be C# inside SSIS.

Comment: A VB.Net script task is also viable